# What did I do wrong on this question?

Tags: probability

> The average daily temperature in °F in a certain town is a normal random variable $T$ with $\mu=30$ and $\sigma=12$. The daily heating cost $C$, in dollars, for a building is related to $T$ by $C=-100T+13000$. What is the probability that the daily heating cost for this building on a typical day will exceed $\$11,500$?

$$\mathbb P(X>11500)=\mathbb P\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)=\frac{11500-30}{12}=955$$
$$C=-100\cdot955+13000=-82500$$
I know my answer is dead wrong. How do I do this problem the right way?

Comment: Notice that probability is a number between 0 and 1 and you got a number in the order of hundreds!

Comment: Well, the moral of the story is that randomly combining numbers from your problem with arithmetic isn’t an effective problem solving strategy! Time to slow down and think about what you’re doing.

Comment: @obsolutemal Please don't remove context for your question after the question is already answered ... if any other users find this post with the context removed they won't find it helpful. I've reverted your edit - let me know if that's a problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
P((C > 11500) &= P(-100T+13000 > 11500)\\
&= P (-100T>11500-13000)\\
&=P\left(T<\frac{13000-11500}{100}\right)
\end{align}

Hopefully you can finish the question.

As an exercise, you might like to think about what distribution does $C$ follows given that you know that distribution of $T$.

Comment: ah ok, after I get the quotient of that problem, I just look at the chart right?

Comment: depends on what to you mean by "quotient of that problem".

Comment: Wait nvm.  I meant do 13000-11500/100 which = 15 (quotient).  Then, look at the chart to see what value you get.

Comment: Hint: what distribution does $T$ follows again?

Answer (score 0):

$$
P(11500 < C) = P(11500 < -100T + 13000 ) = P(100T < 1500) = P(T < 15)
$$
$$
P(T < 15) = P( T - 30 < -15) = P((T - 30)/12 < -1.25) = P(Z < -1.25)
$$
where $Z$ is a standardized normal random variable.  That probability is 10.56%.

Comment: How did P(T < 15) turn into and P(T-30 < -15) turn into P(Z < -1.25).  Also, how did you get 10.56%?  I know what Z represents but how did you get the aforementioned numbers?

Comment: 1. Take 30 away from both sides
2. Divide both sides by 12,  You get $(T - \mu)/\sigma$
3. You need to look it up in a table of normal random variables.  I used this calculator  http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html